# Wiki Using GVim?

Tags: wiki, vim, textmate

I've been using TextMate on the Mac for a while, and have really appreciated the Plain Text Wiki bundle that lets me construct a wiki from plain text files and simple markup.

Does anyone know if there's a similar extension for GVim? (Either that, or has anyone ported TextMate to Linux?)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few indeed.

Deplete - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=861

vimwiki - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2226

vimwiki seems quite simple, but I think that Deplete has better markup language.

Answer (score 1):

[Vimwiki](http://code.google.com/p/vimwiki/) -- is what I use daily. Easy to install, easy to use.